# Using ActionMailer to send mail at chosen times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, delayed-job

So I'm trying to get my rails application to send particular emails at selected times, which are chosen by the user. Basically, in a form the user types in the subject and body of the email, and selects a Datetime to specify when he wishes that that email be sent. All of this information would be stored in a model.

How can I have rails send the email at the specified date and time? I've tried using the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem, but haven't had much success.

Should I be using Cron jobs? Or is there a gem out there suited specifically for this task? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why not delayed job ? `YourMailer.delay(run_at: ...).the_mail` should work

Comment: Thanks @tight. That works extremely well and saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Clockwork gem](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) or [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Answer (score 0):

[Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/) would be good bet. [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) is railscasts for same.